# Передача значения переменной в другой класс PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qthread, qmainwindow

Нужно передать значение введённое пользователем в *GUI* в другой класс. 
Не получается это сделать, помогите пожалуйста. 
Всё лишнее из кода удалил.

```
import sys
import PyQt5.QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal


class MyApp(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Latency = 0.10  # Сюда нужно передать значение

    def run(self):
        print(self.Latency)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Application")
        self.resize(400, 200)
        self.line_set_t1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0.1", self)
        self.line_set_t1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 70, 40, 22))
        self.btn_set_t1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Apply", self)
        self.btn_set_t1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 40, 22))
        self.btn_set_t1.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_set_t1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_latency(self.line_set_t1.text()))

    def change_latency(self, text):
        self.Latency = text  # Это значение нужно передать
        self.ma = MyApp(self)
        self.ma.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спросите если что-то не понятно.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QPushButton, \
    QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QRect


class Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, latency):                                     # <----
        super().__init__()
        self.latency = latency                                       # <----

    def run(self):
        print(f'\nself.latency = {self.latency}')                    # <----


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                              # !!!
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                   # !!!
        
        self.line_set_t1 = QLineEdit("0.1", self.centralWidget)
        self.line_set_t1.setGeometry(QRect(25, 70, 40, 22))
        
        self.btn_set_t1 = QPushButton("Apply", self.centralWidget)
        self.btn_set_t1.setGeometry(QRect(70, 70, 40, 22))
        self.btn_set_t1.clicked.connect(self.change_latency)

    def change_latency(self):
        latency = self.line_set_t1.text()                            # <----
        
        self.thread = Thread(latency)                                # <----
        self.thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Application")
    w.resize(400, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее правильный вариант, который не будет нарушать общий вид параметров инициализатора `QtCore.QThread`, - это использовать первый, обязательный аргумент (родитель класса `MyApp`, экземпляр `MainWindow`). Через него доступны все атрибуты и методы `MainWindow`.

Чтобы это сделать, добавьте сохранение параметра `Latency` через родителя:

```python
# класс MyApp, метод __init__
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    parent = args[0]  # Здесь находится экземпляр MainWindow
    self.Latency = parent.get_latency()
```

И получение параметра через метод:

```python
# класс MainWindow
def get_latency(self):
    return self.Latency
```

---

Итоговый код:

```python
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MyApp(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        parent = args[0]
        self.Latency = parent.get_latency()

    def run(self):
        print(self.Latency)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Application")
        self.resize(400, 200)
        self.line_set_t1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("0.1", self)
        self.line_set_t1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 70, 40, 22))
        self.btn_set_t1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Apply", self)
        self.btn_set_t1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 40, 22))
        self.btn_set_t1.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_set_t1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.change_latency(self.line_set_t1.text()))

    def change_latency(self, text):
        self.Latency = text
        self.ma = MyApp(self)
        self.ma.start()

    def get_latency(self):
        return self.Latency


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```